# Changing Provision Profile for Push Notification System

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification

I will implement push notification to my iphone app.
I have created app id with wildcard before i have my provision profile and successfully test the app with my device.

Now i want to test my app with notification.

So i created a new app id without wildcard, created the certificates, i downloaded the provision profile and added to my provision profile list.

Now how can I change my projects provision profile? I delete the old one (the one with the wildcard) but it says there is no valid provision profile..

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode, select your target and go to "Build settings". Search for "Code Signing Identity". There is a pop-up where you select the profile.

Comment: If the one that I want to choose is greyed out. Does it means there is something missing in the configuration of the provision profile?

Comment: That probably means that the profile is not valid for this App Id.

Comment: Sorry, not without looking in your iOS developer account :-) - But there are a lot of tutorials around how to create provisioning profiles and all that stuff.